# Return JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm pulling in XML data and I need to return it to the front end as JSON.

I'm processing user input via AJAX like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/process.php',
         data: {category: 'sportingGoods'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      console.log(output);
                  }
});
```

This is sent to process.php

```
if(isset($_POST['category']) && !empty($_POST['category'])){
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    //echo $category;

    switch($category){
        case 'automotive': 
            $amazon->automotive; 
            break;
        case 'sportingGoods': 
            echo $amazon->sportingGoods(); 
            break;

    }
}
```

Then, I access a method in a class. In this case, `$amazon->sportingGoods()`

Now, `sportingGoods()` does a bunch of stuff, then returns a result set like this:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($signedUrl);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $products = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    return $products;
```

The XML and JSON data is there. I can `print_r($products)` and `print_r($xml)` and see the results in the console. However, when I try and return it, I don't get anything. So, am I not returning an object? How can I gain access to the result?

Comment: You need to echo out the $products

Comment: @Maxxi doesn't work. I just get `Array`

Comment: Why 2 uses of `json_encode()` in `sportingGoods()`? jQuery will likely decode one round, but you're probably left needing to decode the other -- `console.log($.parseJSON(output));`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you were decoding your JSON object before echoing it. You need to echo out the JSON object. Then as Jonathan says, parse the JSON with $.parseJSON() in the client

Comment: using json_encode you should also add to your ajax request that: dataType: "json", so that you can work with objects. In any case, **return** isn't enough, you have **echo** what you want to send to the client.

Comment: @briosheje There is an `echo` already before the call to `sportingGoods()`, within the `switch..case`.

Comment: Isn't a `return` statements outside a function a syntax error?

Comment: @FelixKling the only return I see is within his class function (from what he has put in the question anyways...)

Comment: @FelixKling that was a code snippet. It was part of a method

Comment: @FelixKling 2 uses? There is one encode and one decode. I guess my mistake was decoding it at that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo out your json and then stop the script. From there, you'll use parseJSON to convert the json response into a js array.

Try this:

Your `$.ajax({`:

```
success: function( output ) {
    var response = $.parseJSON( output );
    // do something with your js array
},
```

and in `sportingGoods()`:

```
return json_encode( $xml );
```

Comment: There already is an echo made from the return of that function (sportingGoods), though not for automotive.

Comment: Thanks! That helps. I'm now seeing the object in the console.

Comment: Welcome. Don't forget to use `die()` or `exit()` after you `echo` the response

Comment: @Jon Is your point that I should be able to return a result from `sportingGoods` and echo it with the switch? That was my intention at first. Not sure why that doesn't work.

Comment: @PaulDessert Yes, though, you return the decoded json (ie a php array) from your function, and when you just `echo` an array, all you will get is `Array`, so you should have your function return the `json_encode`'d version.  ie `return $json;` rather than `return $products;`